# How do I output JSON data that has mutiple arrays with in it? Using an Interface?

Tags: json, angular, observable

So I am still kind of a novice at Angular 2. My API call returns an object with several arrays and objects within it.

This is the JSON object I receive when i make the get request

```
{"report":[{"customer_name":"kaminto" , 
"customer_address":"Second","tel_no":"Second","id":"15","order_no":"RC13",
"total_amount":"28000","amount_paid":"30000","balance":"-2000",
"sale_date":"2017-08-15" ,"customer_id":"21"},"}], "message":"success" , 
"totalSales":[{"amount_paid":"1174300"}]}
```

I want to output the customer_name and address but they are within the Report array.

Using observables, How can I save this information into objects that i can bind to the html.

Please help.

Comment: Why can't you just display the information on the html as is in the array? Your information is already in objects. The objects are just also contained in an array. Can the `report` property contain more than 1 object in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that object from Observable? Yes, it is not necessary if you only need value of two properties. Something like this should help:

```
customer_name;
customer_address;

yourObservable.map(allReports => allReports.map(report => report
.map(val => { this.customer_name = val.customer_name; 
this.customer_address = val.customer_address } ));
```

Comment: I have tested this out as well and it appears to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

I know this is embarrassing, but i solved it. I just had to add the string type and array brackets to the interface report variable.

```
export interface ISalesReport{
 report:string[];
 message:string;
totalSales:string[];
}
```

I don't know exactly why, but after i did this, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you called your service in your component that returns an observable of the GET call.

In your Service,

```
getCall() {
 return this.http.get(...).map((res) => res.json());
}
```

In your Component, (say you assign to a property),

```
responseObj: Observable<any>;

// say you receive values in ngOnInit(),

ngOnInit() {
 this.responseObj = this.service.getCall();
}
```

In your html, use the `async` pipe for eternally binding it to the observable,

```
<div [innerHTML]="(responseObj | async)?.report[0].customer_name"></div>
<div [innerHTML]="(responseObj | async)?.report[0].customer_address"></div>
```

Hope it helps.